# How to find multiple financial years form start date and finish date in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I'm in a situation to write SQL query in MySQL database that dynamically handles populating Financial years.

Financial starts from '01 July'  and finishes at '30 June'

When start date and finish date is in the same financial year then for example : '2018-19' with only 1 record

**Scenario 1**: IF startDate (DD-MM-YYYY format) = 02-07-2018 and FinishDate (DD-MM-YYYY format) = 21-06-2019  then the Financial year will be '2018-19' with only 1 record.

**Scenario 2**: IF startDate (DD-MM-YYYY format) = 13-07-2018 and FinishDate (DD-MM-YYYY format) = 17-02-2020  then the Financial year will be '2018-19' as record 1 and  record 2 as '2019-20'

***When the data for startdate and finishdate keeps changing the SQL code should dynamically update the Financial year accordingly.***

**Input Table Data:**

[image]

```
**SQL statements to create some scenario based data.**

CREATE TABLE Test1(
StartDate date,
FinishDate date);

Insert into Test1(StartDate,FinishDate) values ('02-07-2018','21-06-2019');
Insert into Test1(StartDate,FinishDate) values ('13-07-2018','17-02-2020');
Insert into Test1(StartDate,FinishDate) values ('05-05-2018','04-10-2019');
Insert into Test1(StartDate,FinishDate) values ('09-02-2018','21-11-2023');

Select * from Test1;
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Thanks in advance

Swetha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a multi-part solution.  First, you are not even showing a possible Fiscal Calendar to work with.  As such, I am dynamically building one.  You just need to use a table name for the inner query based on the number of years you want to cover.  It can be any table as long as it has that many rows in it.   Ex: You want to forecast up to 10 years, the table needs at least 10 rows.

```
select
      @beginFY := date_add( @beginFY, interval 1 year ) BeginFY,
      @endFY := date_add( @endFY, interval 1 year ) EndFY,
      concat( Date_Format( @beginFY, '%Y' ),'-', Date_Format(@endFY, '%y')) FiscalYear
   from
      AnyTableWith10Records,
      -- basis to START your fiscal years.  I am force-setting
      -- the beginning and ending to July 1, June 30 respectively
      -- but starting 2016
      ( select @beginFY := '2016-07-01',
           @endFY := '2017-06-30' ) sqlvars
   limit 10
```

The above query will create a result set such as

```
BeginFY     EndFY       FiscalYear
2017-07-01  2018-06-30  2017-18
2018-07-01  2019-06-30  2018-19
2019-07-01  2020-06-30  2019-20
...
2026-07-01  2027-06-30  2026-27
```

So at this point, I have every possible fiscal year record, its own begin/end dates for comparison purposes and the formatted fiscal year for representation in your final output.

Now, take that entire query and join to your test table as below.

```
select
      date_format( T.StartDate, '%d-%b-%y' ) StartDate,
      date_format( T.FinishDate, '%d-%b-%y' ) FinishDate,
      FY.FiscalYear
   from
      ( select
              @beginFY := date_add( @beginFY, interval 1 year ) BeginFY,
              @endFY := date_add( @endFY, interval 1 year ) EndFY,
              concat( Date_Format( @beginFY, '%Y' ),'-', Date_Format(@endFY, '%y')) FiscalYear
           from
              AnyTableWith10Records,
              ( select @beginFY := '2016-07-01',
                       @endFY := '2017-06-30' ) sqlvars
           limit 10 ) FY
        JOIN test1 T
            on ( FY.BeginFY <= T.StartDate AND T.StartDate <= FY.EndFY )
            OR ( FY.BeginFY <= T.FinishDate AND T.FinishDate <= FY.EndFY )
            OR ( T.StartDate < FY.BeginFY AND FY.EndFY < T.FinishDate )
   order by
      T.StartDate,
      T.FinishDate,
      FY.BeginFY
```

Notice the JOIN condition.  I have 3 criteria and any one of them is valid.
1 based on the start date is ANYWHERE within ANY of the fiscal year begin/end dates.

2 based on the finish date is ANYWHERE within ANY of the fiscal year begin/end dates.

3 The fiscal year is COMPLETELY WITHIN the start/finish such as your Feb 9, 2018 through Nov 21, 2023.  The 2019-20, 2020-21, 2021-22 and 2022-2023 are ALL completely encompassed within your start/finish and will be included in final output.

For display result, I sorted based on the start date and then the fiscal year it qualified against.  You can always tweak it once you get results you are expecting.